# how to add class to django ModelForms file field

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to add class for my file field as other elements(while I can't use `attrs={"rows": "1", "class": "form-control"}` I've no idea how to go on), couldn't find any guides about that every where they applied that on other fields.
forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import MedicalRecords

class UpdateMedicalRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MedicalRecords
        fields = ("title", "file", "doctor")

        widgets = {
            "title": forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows": "", "class": "form-control"}),
             "file": ?? (how to add class as above),
        }
```

Comment: Style admin panel ? is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per Django widget classes (see this link for available types of widget/html input types):](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#built-in-widgets)

```
from django import forms
from .models import MedicalRecords

class UpdateMedicalRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # we can directly specify attributes to individual fields like this
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'title_class_name', 'id':'title_id'}))
    file = forms.ImageField(widget = forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'file_class_name', 'id':'file_id'}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = MedicalRecords
        fields = ("title", "file", "doctor")
        
        # or we can use widgets like this
        widgets = {
            "title": forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows": "", "class": "title_class_name"}),
             "file": forms.FileInput(attrs={"rows": "", "class": "file_class_name"}),
        }
```